# получить заголовки в скрипте асинхронного скачивания apache.http.client

Tags: java, сеть

Подскажите как можно в этом скрипте получить headers все в виде массива ?

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Async;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Content;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;


/**
 * Java mass loader
 */
public class MassLoader {

    /**
     * Main method
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
        builder.setScheme("http").setHost("google.com").setPath("/");

        URI requestURL = null;
        try {
            requestURL = builder.build();
        } catch (URISyntaxException use) {}

        ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        Async async = Async.newInstance().use(threadpool);
        final Request request = Request.Get(requestURL);

        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            Future<Content> future = async.execute(request, new FutureCallback<Content>() {
                public void failed (final Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage() +": "+ request);
                }

                public void completed (final Content content) {

                    System.out.println("Request completed: "+ request);
                    System.out.println("Response:\n"+ content.asString());
                }

                public void cancelled () {
                    System.out.print("Cancelled");
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно воспользоваться методом `async.execute` с другой сигнатурой:

```java
<T> Future<T> execute(Request request, ResponseHandler<T> handler)
```

или

```java
<T> Future<T> execute(Request request, ResponseHandler<T> handler, FutureCallback<T> callback)
```

Класс `ResponseHandler<T>` может выглядеть примерно так:

```java
public class ResponseHandlerExample extends BasicResponseHandler{
    public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response){
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        String content = super.handleResponse(response);
        // обработки
        ...
        return content;
    }
}
```

Ну и не забыть проверить код возврата `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`